# boot problem after changing etc/profile

Tags: boot

I changed etc/profile and now my system doesn't start. I have a copy of the original file. Is there a way to replace the corrupt file?
It is Ubuntu 14 on dell vostro laptop.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu Live CD or USB?

Comment: Change it back to what it was.

Comment: thanks for the help. I boot from a live iso changed the profile back and everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to boot from another live iso (Ubuntu cd/dvd/usb), then mount your installed partition and change the file(s) back to what they were. (if that's really the problem)

Comment: did just this and everything works. thanks very much

Comment: @EitanBernstein No problem. If it helped you could select/check-mark my answer to "complete" your question :-)